# Why Kendo ComboBoxFor show 0 instead of property binded model which was passed from another view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am ASP MVC newbie.
I have problem with Kendo ComboBoxFor. I tried dozens of examples from Stack but with no success.

I want to pass two ids from one view to another and use them in two ComboboxFor. In both views I use this same model.
Beneath, there are my two target ids.

**Model**

```
public class Wymiarowanie_PorownajModel
{
    public int Target1 { get; set; }
    public int Target2 { get; set; }
}
```

This is my two approaches to binding this ids in target view. Both not work.
ComboBoxFor display 0 instead of property binded model which was passed from another view. Binded list to ComboboxFor works correctly.

**View**

```
@model WebApp.Models.Wymiarowanie_PorownajModel
<td class="align_center">
            @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.Target1)
            .DataTextField("Opis")
            .DataValueField("Id")
            .Suggest(true)
            .Name("Target1")
            .Filter("contains")
            .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["opis"])
            .Placeholder("Wybierz tłoka bazowego...")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:225px;" })
            )
        </td>
        <td class="align_center">
            @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.Target2)
            .DataTextField("Nazwa").DataValueField("Id")
            .Suggest(true)
            .Filter("contains")
            .Placeholder("Wybierz opcję 1...")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:225px;" })
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("PodajRysunek", "Wymiarowanie_PorownajWymiaryTlokow");
                })
                                 .ServerFiltering(true);
            })
            )
        </td>
```

**Controller**

```
public class Wymiarowanie_PorownajWymiaryTlokowController : Controller
{
  private MainDb db = new MainDb();
  Wymiarowanie_PorownajModel wym = new Wymiarowanie_PorownajModel();

  public ActionResult Index(Wymiarowanie_PorownajModel wymMain)
  {
     wymMain = wym;
     UzupelnijNrRysunku(); 
     return View(wym);
  }

  private void UzupelnijNrRysunku()
  {
     var typ = db.Specyfikacja_V_TlokiZwymiarowaneDoPorownaniaNrRysunku_list
     .Select(c => new
     {
       Id = c.Id,
       Opis = c.Rysunek_Nr_Zmiana
     })
     .OrderBy(e => e.Opis);
     ViewData["opis"] = typ.OrderBy(e => e.Opis);
     ViewData["defaultopis"] = typ.First().Opis;
  }

  public JsonResult PodajRysunek(string text)
  {
      var rysunki =   
      db.Specyfikacja_V_TlokiZwymiarowaneDoPorownaniaNrRysunku_list
      .Select(tlok => new {
         Id = tlok.Id,
         Nazwa = tlok.Rysunek_Nr_Zmiana
      });

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
      {
         rysunki = rysunki.Where(p => p.Nazwa.Contains(text));
      }
      return Json(rysunki, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

I don't have any clue what is wrong. 
Would you like to help me find solution for this error? 
I hope that my code is clear to you Sorry for my English.

Kind Regards

Comment: There seem to be a javascript error on your page. Try to add Javascript Errors Notifier (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-errors-notifie/jafmfknfnkoekkdocjiaipcnmkklaajd) to Chrome and run your page (or view console log) to see if there is any.

Comment: @LongLe : Message from JsEN - "There are no errors on this page :(". No errors also in console log. After one day break with no coding I discovered silly mistake with binding data. I probably needed a rest at work. However, thanks for great add-on to browser!

Comment: Please provide a solution as an answer detailing what exactly you did to fix the problem not as an update to your question. This is to help future visitors understand and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have example how bind data

```
   public ActionResult Products_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    using (var northwind = new NorthwindEntities())
    {
        IQueryable<Product> products = northwind.Products;
        DataSourceResult result = products.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result);
    }
}
```

More information u can find [here](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/ajax-binding)

Comment: Thanks for response but I have problem with normal CombBox, not Grid.
Fortunely, you gave me an idea for solution which I will try.

Comment: Your example from Telerik documentation led me to find an error in my data binding. I solved problem by clearing my code and using examples from documentation. Dziękuję za naprowadzenie. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution an explanation:** I commited rookie's mistake. I messed up instances in my controllers. I wanted to use two separate views with two separate controllers.

I cleaned a reduced my code and put it to one controller.

I have this same model class. Finally, my ComboBoxFor look like example beneath:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.Target)
    .DataTextField("Nazwa").DataValueField("Id")
    .Suggest(true)
    .Filter("contains")
    .Placeholder("Wybierz opcję 1...")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:225px;" })
    .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("PodajRysunek", "Wymiarowanie_Porownaj");
            })
                             .ServerFiltering(true);
        })
            )
```

Now I using only *JsonResult **PodajRysunek*** method to binding list to combobox.

I changed a little bit method for second view which appearence is invoked by button.

```
public ActionResult WymiaryTlokow(Wymiarowanie_PorownajModel wymiarowaniePorownajModel)
    {
        this.wym = wymiarowaniePorownajModel;
        return View(wym);
    }
```

It is never late to learn. :)